# Proving a norm is lipschitz

Tags: linear-algebra, continuity, normed-spaces, lipschitz-functions

Let $M\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$. Define the function $f\colon\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ by $f(x)=\Vert Mx\Vert$. Show that $f$ is Lipschitz.

---

Let $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^n$, then we want to find a $L>0$ such that

$$\Vert f(x)-f(y)\Vert \le L\Vert x-y\Vert$$

---

We have

\begin{align}
\Vert f(x)-f(y)\Vert &= \big\Vert \Vert Mx\Vert-\Vert My\Vert\big\Vert\\
&\le \Vert Mx- My\Vert&\text{reverse triangle ineq.}\\
&\le \Vert M\Vert\Vert x-y\Vert\\
\end{align}

Taking $L=\Vert M\Vert$ we find $f$ is Lipschitz.

---

I have a few questions here, some related to Lipschitz continuity and others related to norms.

- Firstly, is this working correct?
- I notice that we take $L=\Vert M\Vert$ but could we take anything greater than our chosen $L$, in other words, is the Lipschitz constant unique?
- On a side note, is $\Vert \Vert Mx\Vert \Vert=\Vert Mx\Vert$? In general can we say that $\Vert\Vert a\Vert\Vert = \Vert a\Vert$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) A conditional yes. Your proof of the Lipschitz continuity of $f$ is correct, provided you play it completely safe by stating specifically that the matrix norm is induced by the vector norm, i.e.
\begin{equation}
\|M\| = \sup \{ \|Mx\| \: : \: \|x\| \leq 1 \}
\end{equation}
and that $\|z\|$ is merely the absolute value of $z$ when $z \in \mathbb{R}$.

2) Yes, any value larger than $L$ would also serve as a Lipschitz constant for $f$. But $L=\|M\|$ is the smallest value which will work. Simply pick $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\|Mx\| = \|M\|$, $\|x\| = 1$ and $y = 0$.

3) It depends!  $Mx \in \mathbb{R}^n$ whereas $\|Mx\| \in \mathbb{R}$, so you are overloading the notation for $\|\cdot\|$. Refer to the remark I made for point 1).

Comment: On point #1 .- why does the matrix norm need to be induced by the vector norm? I would have thought any submultiplicative matrix norm would work.

Comment: @Robert. If you have $\|Mx\| \leq \|M\| \|x\|$ then, yes, $f$ is Lipschitz continuous. However, we are not dealing with a single matrix norm. There are *two* norms involved. These two functions have different domains, one applies to matrices, the other applies to vectors. A submultiplicative matrix norm satisfies $\|AB\| \leq \|A\| \|B\|$ for square matrices $A$ and $B$, i.e., there is no reference to vectors.

Comment: I guess I was using the "submultiplicative matrix norm" to mean any pair of norms $p, q$ that works or $\lVert AB \rVert \leq \lVert A \rVert_p \lVert B \rVert_q$ for non-square matricies (including vectors) $A$ and $B$. Only some matrix/vector norm pairs meet that inequality, right?

Comment: Yes. Only some pairs satisfy such an inequality. Always be mindful of what you think and what you write. They are not necessarily the same and your writings will most likely be taken literally.