# Is the gradient of l2-norm $\nabla f(x) = \frac{x}{\|x\|}$ globally Lipschitz continuous?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, continuity

The l2-norm function $:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R},\quad f(x)=\|x\|$

The gradient of the l2-norm function $:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n,\quad g(x)=\frac{x}{\|x\|}$

Thanks to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1648275/proving-a-norm-is-lipschitz/1648309), I know that the l2-norm function is globally Lipschitz continuous with Lipschitz constant $1$. But what about the gradient?

In another words, can we have a constant $L$, such that
$$\left\|\frac{x}{\|x\|}-\frac{y}{\|y\|}\right\|\leq L \|x-y\|$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't. If it were, then it would be uniformly continuous, and therefore map Cauchy sequences to Cauchy sequences. But, if we choose $u \in \Bbb{R}^n$ with norm $1$, then the sequence $\frac{(-1)^n}{n}u$ is Cauchy as it converges to $0$, but when mapped under the given function, it produces the sequence $(-1)^nu$, which is not Cauchy.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But why restrict $u$ with norm 1. Can I restrict it with any norm size, it produces the sequence $\frac{(-1)^n u}{\|u\|}$ and it is not Cauchy.

Comment: Because I didn't want to format another fraction, simple as that. :-)